# Core Data NSPredicate for toMany Relationsihp

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, relationship

I've got a problem in the formulation of my query; this is the scenario:

[image: my DB schema]

based on this db schema, I know the naming part sucks a little, but this is 
a project which has been already kicked off, so I've to stick with that.

Now, my goal is to select all the characters with a determined pack_id and a certain category_id, i.e. all the characters from pack 1 in category 5, so this's my NSPredicate

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(category_id == %@) AND (charRelationship.pack_id == %@)", [[cat valueForKey:@"category_id"] stringValue], curPack];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

as soon as the compiler tries to execute the fetchRequest, it crashes and goes SIGABRT.
I really hate the fact that xcode is not even giving me a clue about the exception so that I could figure it out myself. So after blindly trying to fix it with no success, I wonder if there's anybody out there who could help me.
I've already red a ton of other threads on SO and elsewhere, but I couldn't find any solution.

thanks a lot

-k-

Comment: You say that you're trying to get *Characters*, but your `NSFetchRequest` is using the *Category* entity. Which is it?

Comment: I could have done the opposite (starting from Characters) but it doesn't change the fact that I have to handle the cross relation between two separate entities, so doing it in one way or in the other it doesn't change, I just want it to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using ANY for the relationship:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(category_id == %@) AND (ANY charRelationship.pack_id like %@)", [[cat valueForKey:@"category_id"] stringValue], curPack];
```

Comment: ANY was the solution for me to get the relationship recognized. Is category_id a NSString in the database? I'm confused why you use stringValue.

Comment: nope it's a int32, the stringValue was just a desperate attempt :)

Comment: then you shouldn't use stringvalue, if you compare a string with an int it'll never be true (if it doesn't give an error).

Comment: yeah not it kinda works but is not giving me all the records like it should, in example category 1 for pack 0 shall have 11 records, while in this case it returns just 10. I tried replace the ANY with ALL but it's no use. :( And all of these is working with LIKE %@ and stringValue, cuz if I turn that into == %d and intValue nothing works

Comment: ok I think that the problem could be in the database itself. somehow it's laking relationships. but at a mechanical level this seem to work. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Actually you must not store any id separately for an entity that is associated. E.g.: in your case you could just refer to category from the characters entity like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"catRel = %@", cat];
```

However, I'm not sure what are you going to do with the snippet. Am I right that you have a Category entity stored in your 'cat' variable, and just going to select it from the database with the predicate? I would say, that a category_id already identifies your category... whatever, try not user "charRelationship.pasck_id == %@" but load the corresponding Character entity and use "charRelationship = %@" where you just put your entity.